# addClass when a number inside a span is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add class "active" to "fav-contractors" container only when number inside "fav-con-count" span is greater than 0.

This is HTML code

```
<span class="fav-contractors">
    <span class="fav-con-count">7</span>
</span>
```

and this is jQuery code

```
function favCounter() {
    if ($(".fav-con-count").textContent > 0) {
        $(".fav-contractors").addClass("active");
    } 
};

favCounter();
```

Which "if" rule should I use? I also tried something like that but it didn't work:

```
function favCounter() {
    var favValue = $(".fav-con-count").textContent;

    if (+favValue > 0)) {
        $(".fav-contractors").addClass("active");
    } 
};

favCounter();
```

Comment: you are comparing strings text with number....

Comment: Replacing "if ($(".fav-con-count").textContent > 0)" with  "if ($(".fav-con-count").text() > 0)" solves problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node.textContent is JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), not part of the jQuery library per-se. [jQuery uses the `.text()` method](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text by using `textContent` under the hood.  Also, read about jQuery's [toggleClass() method](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), you can use a second boolean parameter instead, making the `if` statement unnecessary.

Since you use classes it's pretty dangerous to just do `$(".fav-contractors").addClass("active");`, since you could:

- have many `.fav-contractors` Elements in a single page and *all* will get the active class
- `$(".fav-con-count").text() > 0` means that only if *the first of that class* Element has text greater than 0 - which might also be incorrect and lead to a buggy undesired behavior.

**Solution**

- Use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate all your elements of a specific class
- Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse to a specific element ancestor (or self)
- (As already mentioned) use [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$(".fav-con-count").each(function() {
  $(this).closest(".fav-contractors").toggleClass("active", $(this).text() > 0);
});
```

```css
.fav-contractors { padding: 1rem; }
.active { background: gold; }
```

```html
<span class="fav-contractors">
  <span class="fav-con-count">7</span>
</span>

<span class="fav-contractors">
  <span class="fav-con-count">0</span>
</span>

<span class="fav-contractors">
  <span class="fav-con-count">3</span>
</span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, you nailed it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.text()` instead of `textContent`

```js
function favCounter() {
    if ($(".fav-con-count").text() > 0) {
        $(".fav-contractors").addClass("active");
    } 
};

favCounter();
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="fav-contractors">
    <span class="fav-con-count">7</span>
</span>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

This is an example of the number 0 not adding the active class

```js
function favCounter() {
    if ($(".fav-con-count").text() > 0) {
        $(".fav-contractors").addClass("active");
    } 
};

favCounter();
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="fav-contractors">
    <span class="fav-con-count">0</span>
</span>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: here's this code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/739ynagh/1/ and it's buggy. Never treat classNames as IDs.

Comment: It's definitely not a bug, your code prints yellow on everything because it checks the first element every time and the number written in it is greater than 0, if you delete the first element you'll see that the code works properly...
The error is in your code

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added for you an example of an answer with the number 0 to show you that it is correct

Comment: @HaimAbeles you're wrong. The jsFiddle example uses **your exact code you suggested in your answer** :) take a closer look. Your example seemingly works because you used mistakenly only **one** element. If you take a close inspection, it uses a class, not an ID, and classes are meant to be reusable. And that's where you code fails. When you reuse your components and have them more than one in the DOM.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the correction